# Word for sentences which read the with their words (not characters!) reversed

Tags: single-word-requests, terminology, sentence-patterns

I am looking for a word for sentences which read the same forwards and when the order of words is reversed?

Just to clarify, I'm not talking about palindromes, in which individual characters are reversed. I’m thinking, instead, of sentences where the characters within words are left alone and the order of the words itself is reversed, for example:

> That is that.

Comment: Kinda *"Jimmy loves Mom" <=> "Mom loves Jimmy"* ?

Comment: Or *Father Charles goes down and ends battle" <=> "Battle ends and down goes Charles' father* / *Fall leaves as soon as leaves fall* / *Girl, bathing on Bikini, eyeing boy, finds boy eyeing bikini on bathing girl.* / *"One for all and all for one."*

Comment: Apart from Tony Blair's famous deflection 'John is John' etc, I don't think this sort of symmetry is possible.

Comment: _Father and me help everyone see or see everyone help me and Father_ That sort of thing (or just half of it) ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After some research I found out that this could either be called a *palindrome*, (This would be used when you want all letters to be the same when read backwards, even though I do believe this rarely occurs in sentences), or a *palingram* (This would be used when the letters themselves do not matter). Ofcourse, in both cases the meaning of the sentence should be the same when read backwards.

I hope this helped you out a bit more.

Answer (score 0):

I believe those are called *palingrams.*

While *palindrome* is an option, *palingram* seems the broader of the two terms, including both reversible letters and reversible words. I am still looking for a somewhat authoritative source to substantiate others who have expressed this view on their own websites, including:http://theenglishdrivenlife.weebly.com/1/previous/2.html and http://www.rinkworks.com/words/palindromes.shtml.